# FileNotFoundError with writing file after succesfull os.makedirs(..., exist_ok=True)

Tags: python, file-not-found

i'm very confused about this error. After i create a folder successfully and try to write a file in python, it throws the Error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

I even tried to build the path with os.cwd() and os.listdir() to get the absolut right path.

how can i resolve this error?
or locate the problem?

```
data= b"this is a test"
filename = os.path.join('DWD_Data', 'Stations', 'test.txt')    
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True)
with open(filename, "wb") as f:
   f.write(data)
```

edit:
ok, after i moved the project to an other directory it works totaly fine.
And it works in the original Project if i try to write in the folder DWD_Data.

And now i have the Problem:
"maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is defined as 260 characters"
and mine is 288 chars.

thanks for the help.

Its seems its not that easy to solve this ... 
does someone have a nice link for a workaround or something?

Comment: You should print the dir and file name for debugging.

Comment: And show the full exception and traceback please

Comment: I updated your example to make it runnable and it works for me.

Comment: Same. Please show more info. Voting to close as unable to reproduce until you change that.